# Elasticsearch .NET Nest API vs HTTP RESTful API performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new in elasticsearch. we have a project with a lot of user interaction. Backend of the project is ASP.NET MVC and frontend is Angularjs. Backend and Frontend communicate with WEB API.
We use SQL Server for data storage and we'll use elasticsearch for Search Engine and retrieving data from server.
Elasticsearch can work upon of Nest and javascript API, is there any difference in performance between Nest and JS API (Specially in very big and complicated queries)?

Comment: That article may help to have an opinion: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-interfacing-elasticsearch-picking-client

Comment: There will no major performance issues between both approaches.
In my opinion your code base will be more clean and clear using Nest.

Answer (score 4):

[NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html), the high level Elasticsearch .NET client, uses Elasticsearch's json REST API through [Elasticsearch.Net](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net.html), the low level .NET client, and exposes all of the endpoints with strong types, using [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization.

Elasticsearch.Net itself does not expose all endpoints with strong types but can work with `string`, `byte[]`, `object`, and `string`, `byte[]` and `object` collections. It uses a simple json serializer to handle serialization so has no dependencies on any other serialization library.

NEST aims to be a fast client that "just works" for any scenario in which you want to use Elasticsearch. *If* you're using a limited subset of the API, you may be able to improve serialization with custom serializers using something like [JIL](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil), and, if the approach is generic, [we'd love to know](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) to see if it could be rolled into NEST. You can write your own json serializer by implementing [`IElasticsearchSerializer`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/9cab2174dd988fb8cf6b440fdd24d32517eab5b0/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Serialization/IElasticsearchSerializer.cs).